# Will following query be executed?

Tags: mysql

Consider below table.

```
 CREATE TABLE `Emp` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userName` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `modiTime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Suppose there is following entry :

```
insert into `Emp` (`id`, `userName`, `modiTime`) values('1','test','2017-02-02 14:05:26');
```

Epoch Unix Time Stamp of '2017-02-02 14:05:26' is 1486044326. Is it possible to execute following query ? Please explain with reason since I am newbie.

```
SELECT * FROM Emp WHERE modiTime = 1486044326;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you even do this? `moditime` is a datetime; `1486044326` is a number. You wouldn't compare a datetime with a number.

If you want to look for a date use a literal that MySQL accepts for a date literal, e.g. '2017-02-02 14:05:26'.

```
WHERE modiTime = '2017-02-02 14:05:26'
```

(MySQL doesn't support the standard SQL syntax `WHERE modiTime = TIMESTAMP '2017-02-02 14:05:26'` for datetime literals.)

If you only have this unix number, then convert it to datetime. MySQL offers the function `FROM_UNIXTIME` for this. This converts to a string in a valid datetime format (namely 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS').

```
WHERE modiTime = FROM_UNIXTIME(1486044326)
```

This implicitly casts the result string to datetime. If you want to be thorough, you can cast this explicitly, thus showing you know the result to be a string in a valid datetime literal format:

```
WHERE modiTime = CAST(FROM_UNIXTIME(1486044326) AS DATETIME)
```